# How to see what kafka client application connected from a certain ip address?

Tags: apache-kafka

Although kafka clients are authenticated, and can be restricted (authorized) to connect only from allowed ip addresses, on these app servers multiple applications may be deployed, and it would be beneficial if kafka admin could somehow match certain connection (visible only via netstat on kafka server machine!) to a certain application, either by an application tag passed explicitely by kafka client, or by command name that started the kafka client application passed by the local client operating system to a kafka client (and visible via ps command on unix), and passed through kafka client to kafka broker. Is there already such a possibility?
That would imply that connections are held as browsable objects within kafka, somewhere, either in some internal topic, or in its zookeeper.
Alternatively, at least displaying the authorized principal that initiated connection would also do. That is a question for both consumers and producers.

Comment: if you launch kafka-consumer-groups.sh, you can check the actual live consumer connections, with their corresponding source IPs (may be helpful) - check https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSsmRUmrOTmM9EJxDJjFhozgy19rZZbUScHtnP-tdfHSy6R6SkU

Comment: Thanks, but kafka clients are producers too, which may also hold long living connections, not just consumers, ...

Comment: ... besides that, it would be useful that not just host, but port also is displayed there, and the authorized principal that initiated connection (be that ANONYMOUS or authenticated one).